# The Behavior "EventToCommand" of Blend4

Tags: mvvm-light, expression-blend-4

I have already installed Blend4.Yesterday i installed the mvvmlight.But I haven't found my Blend4 have the behavior "EventToCommand".It's very important for my project.So how to solve it?

Comment: You may consider improving your question a bit because it's quite vague.  
I'm assuming that you simply forgot to add a reference to the toolkit in your Blend project (see my answer), since you didn't mention doing that step in your question.  However, I've also included a link to the EventToCommand page at GalaSoft's site that explains the entire process in detail.  Please mark this answer as the "accepted" answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Directions for adding EventToCommand to Blend can be found [here](http://blog.galasoft.ch/archive/2009/11/05/mvvm-light-toolkit-v3-alpha-2-eventtocommand-behavior.aspx). Just scroll down the page until you see "Features, Usage: In Expression Blend".

If you've already installed the MVVM-Light Toolkit, as you say, then simply right-click on your "References" folder in Blend and click "Add Reference". Browse for your GalaSoft.MvvmLight.dll file and press OK. Repeat this process for the following dll's as well:

GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.dll

System.Windows.Interactivity.dll *(contains the base code for all behaviors, so you may already have a reference for this)*